# postgres: EOF detected for even simple queries

Tags: postgresql

I'm running a postgres server locally on my computer and it seems that even the simple queries like the one below is giving me an `EOF detected` error.

For instance, this query

```
ALTER TABLE maintab ADD COLUMN testing numeric;
UPDATE maintab SET testing = numeric1 * numeric2;
```

And similar activities will throw an EOF error. I'm also running PostGIS with QGIS and my spatial queries, no matter how simple, will throw this error.

I've look around at forums and documentation but nothing can seem to help solve this problem. Is there anything I can do to stop this?

**EDIT**

I ran a check on my error logs after doing some Googling. Found these logs, not sure what to make of them

```
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [1138-4] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [1208-3] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [1208-4] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [1208-5] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [1138-5] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2015-09-04 11:18:31 EDT [3861-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-09-04 15:08:49 EDT
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [3861-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [3861-3] LOG:  record with zero length at 1D/123A250
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [3861-4] LOG:  redo is not required
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [3861-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [1138-6] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-09-04 11:18:32 EDT [3865-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-09-04 16:07:22 EDT [1122-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-09-04 16:06:25 EDT
2015-09-04 16:07:22 EDT [1179-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1122-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1122-3] LOG:  record with zero length at 1D/123A320
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1122-4] LOG:  redo is not required
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1122-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1114-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT [1183-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-09-04 12:15:05 EDT [1183-2] LOG:  stats collector's time 2015-09-04 16:07:23.363257-04 is later than backend local time 2015-09-04 12:15:05.07308-04
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1114-2] LOG:  server process (PID 3824) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1114-4] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1183-3] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1183-4] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1183-5] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [1114-5] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2015-09-04 12:17:34 EDT [3828-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-09-04 16:07:23 EDT
2015-09-04 12:17:35 EDT [3828-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2015-09-04 12:17:35 EDT [3828-3] LOG:  redo starts at 1D/123A388
2015-09-04 12:17:35 EDT [3828-4] LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 1C/F9258000 in log segment 000000010000001D00000001, offset 2457600
2015-09-04 12:17:35 EDT [3828-5] LOG:  redo done at 1D/1255C18
2015-09-04 12:17:36 EDT [3828-6] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-09-04 12:17:36 EDT [3833-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-09-04 12:17:36 EDT [1114-6] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: [at least] maybe add a semicolon? (it are two statements)

Comment: Sorry I'll add that to my question. I usually put semicolons but in this case, this isn't it.

Comment: secure (ssh) connection?

Comment: I assume this error is coming from the client (psql? or some other application?). It might be helpful if you can paste the full error you have in the question. Also, is there anything unusual in the postgresql server log?

Comment: Please show the full, exact error text. Also take a look at the PostgreSQL server error log, see if there's anything informative there.

Comment: I ran ```tail - 100 /var/log/postgres``` and all it said was ```==> standard input <==```

Comment: I've ran the logs and put them up in my question. I hope this helps!